# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind

Valgrind is giving me 
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) and
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
errors on my current code:

```
    void createMonsters(Game *game) {
       (void) game;

       Creature *nr;

       int x = 0;
       int r = 0;
       int y = 0;
       int check = 0;
       int c = game->opts.numMonsters;
       int nrm=0;


       nr=malloc( sizeof (Creature) * c);


        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){

            game->numMonsters=nrm;
            r = rand()%2;
            x = rand() % game->opts.mapWidth;
            y = rand() % game->opts.mapHeight;
            check=1;

            while(check!=2){
                check = isBlocked(game,x,y);
                if(check==1){
                    x = rand() % game->opts.mapWidth;
                    y = rand() % game->opts.mapHeight;
            }
                else{

                    nr[i].pos.y=y;
                    nr[i].pos.x=x;
                    nr[i].attack=attackPunch;
                    nrm += 1;
                    check=2;
            }
        }

            if(r==0){
                nr[i].name[0] = 'C';
                nr[i].maxhp = 15;
                nr[i].hp = nr[i].maxhp;
                nr[i].sign = 'C';
        }
            else{
                nr[i].name[0] = 'D';
                nr[i].maxhp = 50;
                nr[i].hp = nr[i].maxhp;
                nr[i].sign = 'D';


        }    

            game->monsters=nr;

        }
       game->numMonsters=nrm;
    }


int isBlocked(Game *game, int x, int y)
    {
            (void) game;
            (void) x;
            (void) y;
            if(x>game->opts.mapWidth || y>game->opts.mapHeight){
                return 1;
            }        }

            if(game->numMonsters!=0){                   
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < game->numMonsters; i++){
                Creature *monst = &game->monsters[i];
                if (monst->pos.x == x && monst->pos.y == y){
                    return 1;
                }}
            }



            if(game->map.tile[y][x]==TILE_OPEN || game->map.tile[y][x]==TILE_ROOM){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                return 1;
            }

     }
```

Valgrind points to nr=malloc( sizeof (Creature) * c);
So what I'm doing wrong?

```
    typedef struct creature_st {
        char name[20];  // name of the monster
        char sign;  // character that represents monster on the game display
        Point pos;  // location of the monster
        float hp;  // current hitpoints
        unsigned int maxhp;  // maximum hitpoints
        void (*move)(struct game_st *, struct creature_st *);  // current movement algorithm for monster
        void (*attack)(struct game_st *, struct creature_st *);  // current attack algorithm for monster
    } Creature;
```

Full valgrind error:

==386== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)   ==386==    at 0x4C2C1B8: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) ==386==    by 0x403F54: test_createMonsters (test_source.c:179) ==386==    by 0x409377: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) ==386==    by 0x4057C9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) ==386==    by 0x405464: main (test_source.c:529) ==386==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation ==386==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) ==386==    by 0x4026C2: createMonsters (monster.c:288) ==386==    by 0x403ADF: test_createMonsters (test_source.c:119) ==386==    by 0x409377: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) ==386==    by 0x4057C9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) ==386==    by 0x405464: main (test_source.c:529) ==386==

```
    typedef struct game_st {
        Map map;
        unsigned int numMonsters;  // number of elements in 'monsters' array
        Creature *monsters;  // dynamic array of all monsters
        Point position;  // current position of the player
        float hp;  // hit points, should never be higher than 'maxhp'
        unsigned int maxhp;  // maximum hit points
        Options opts;
    } Game;
```

Comment: is Creature a complete type here? If this is a typedef on a struct is it's definition included?

Comment: Added def of Creature struct

Comment: What I am asking is whether that file has access to that definition of struct?

Comment: Oh, yes it has access to def.

Comment: In a context like this, you should really show the full error message from `valgrind`.  Things like the stack trace where the problem is detected and any previous comments it passed are probably relevant.  At the least, without seeing the `valgrind` trace, I'm not going to attempt to guess what you're doing wrong.  What's the value in `game->opts.numMonsters`?  It's a little surprising if `valgrind` waits until you allocate memory to report problems, but that's used to determine `c`.  Also consider the techniques that create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Applying those principles to your code may help.

Comment: Added full error message. Valgrind gives same error even if I change c to random direct value, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I suspect it's something in your game_st struct.  Do you have a string in there?

Comment: Posted def for game_st.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized value has been created somewhere in your code and that function accesses that value. Use [--track-origins=yes](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#opt.track-origins) option to valgrind to track where that value comes from.